# На сервер приходят странные запросы

Tags: node.js, http, amazon

У меня NodeJs сервер на порте 2222 на хостинге амазона, с присоединенным к нему доменом .ru, заметил, что переодически в консоли NodeJs появляются такие запросы:

`HEAD / 302 0ms - 32b`

`GET http://clientapi.ipip.net/echo.php?info=20181015201543`

`GET http://5.188.210.12/echo.php 404 69ms - 6.33kb`

`GET /xxbb 404 157ms - 6.33kb`

`POST /fndex.html?id=1 404 86ms - 6.33kb`

`GET /HNAP1/ 404 51ms - 6.33kb`

`GET /robots.txt 404 91ms - 6.33kb`

Вопрос заключается в том, что это может значить и не является ли это признаком чего-то опасного?

Comment: это запросы к тому, что до тебя жило на твоём ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HEAD / 302 0ms - 32b
GET /robots.txt 404 91ms - 6.33kb
```

Нормальные запросы поисковиков и клиентов

```
GET http://clientapi.ipip.net/echo.php?info=20181015201543
GET http://5.188.210.12/echo.php 404 69ms - 6.33kb
GET /xxbb 404 157ms - 6.33kb
POST /fndex.html?id=1 404 86ms - 6.33kb
GET /HNAP1/ 404 51ms - 6.33kb
```

сканирование вашего сайта на различные уязвимости

> не является ли это признаком чего-то опасного?

все ресурсы в интернете подвергаются сканированию на уязвимости. Роботы ищут непропатченные форумы, сайты с уязвимостями авторизации, сайты со словарными паролями.

Если следите за своим сайтом, все вовремя патчите, обновляете и следите за его безопасностью, то ничего страшного ему не грозит.

Если же недоделанный сайт в разработке с простыми паролями выложили в общий доступ, то велика вероятность, что роботы найдут свою жертву

Comment: Проблема в том, что мне непонятно откуда берутся эти поисковики и клиенты

Comment: Зачастую просто сканируют подсеть по стандартным портам

Comment: Под клиентом подразумевается обычный браузер. Хром, например, не спрашивая пользователя, пытается запросить стандартные файлы типа иконок